# Differential amplifier or long tail pair with gain = 1, boundaries for input voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier

The question assumes DC is used, and no gain. Long tail pair is counterintuitive to me. In my limited understanding, it seems like the transistor is maximally forward biased relatively easy. But to be able to actually subtract a significant range of "numbers",  differential amplifiers would have to be able to continuously increase current (or reduce resistance) as input voltage increases. What are the boundaries for how base responds to input voltage? Can anyone understand why it seems counter-intuitive?

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you have the output polarity wrong in your illustration. If you switch the + and - the functionality should become more clear.

Comment: Counter-intuitive? Normally, resistors, currents and power supplies are chosen so that the  common emitter node is app. at ground potential.

Comment: the polarity does not matter really, it is just a convention which should be treated as + and which as -. and the schematic does not really matter because everyone knows what a long tail pair or differential amplifier is, so it is already in the topic. anyone who could contribute to it would already have functionality clear, because they are standard and extremely basic components.

Comment: With an op amp for example that has differential amplifier as one of 3 (or something like that) main components, you can feed in 0 volt on one input, 5 v on the other, no resistors in between the voltage and the gate to lower the voltage, and connect the output to the 0 volt input to raise it to 5 volt by using the differential amplifier that will continue to output a non equal result until the inputs reach same value. What I have a hard time seeing, is how the base at transistors continuous to have a graded response for the entire range of voltages.

Comment: I basically wonder: Do bases on the 2 transistors in a differential amplifier have graded response for entire range of input voltages they use? Why it is counter-intuitive, I have studied (I am very much beginner but studied a little here and there out of strong interest) digital angle of electronics mostly, because I am mostly interested in computers. And there, transistors are supposed to have more of an "all or nothing" response, or, binary. 1 or 0. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: So to me, that a base should continuously, and linearly, increase current through transistor in the way diff amp seems to do, unless I misunderstand how they work (one reason I ask, because if you miss something, it takes forever even if you look), is, like I said, counter-intuitive. I don't claim any merit for that, it is just how it is.

Comment: The resistor at the "tail" of the differential pair limits the current. If the transistors are current controlled, that explains where the resistor was. I did not pay attention to it, and was using 741 op amp with multiple volt input without any resistor, and did not see one in schematic for it. Clearly I am not very good at reading the schematic, since I was only looking at one side of base emitter path (as dumb beginners will tend to do maybe, at least I did), and @Hearth pointed it out.

Comment: That "op amp" is always presented as "black box" contributed to me missing this, I deliberately skipped that approach because it is almost always easier to learn detail version, regardless of field.

Comment: There was things needed. Why I asked. In ICs you say they use a different approach, good point. The point is I just copy pasted some image, the image was irrelevant really. I stated that already.

Comment: Discussion between jonk and Doge has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131549/discussion-on-question-by-doge-differential-amplifier-or-long-tail-pair-with-gai).

Comment: Hi @LvW. I explain in question now what was counter-intuitive. @ Hearth gave me the answer so I can explain now. I understood transistors in a digital context, and a shallow understanding was "good enough" for a lot. In digital circuits, the emitter is grounded. When the input reaches 0.7 volt, the transistor is maximally on. What I did not know is that by adding a resistor after the emitter, input can be higher because it is the difference that matters, but, the emitter voltage will also follow the base voltage as less voltage drop happens over transistor. Second part was really why I asked.

Comment: That the voltage difference is what matters, I could have figured out on my own eventually. But I knew there was something I would have to ask about. And it was that the emitter voltage _follows the base_. Super interesting, very happy to learn, appreciate everyone who contributed to pointing out that simple fact. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

What I missed is two things. 1) it is the difference in voltage at the base and emitter that matters. As a beginner, I was thinking an input of 0.7 volt must "max" things. Very dumb error, but, sometimes it is like that. And 2) increasing base voltage and conductance through transistor, will reduce resistance in transistor and voltage drop over it, which increases voltage after it. So, the voltage at emitter follows the voltage at the base, allowing even wider range of input voltages.

The second part is likely what I was asking for with the question (the first I could have figured out myself eventually, using internet, but I knew there was some part I would need to ask about. ) I could not intuit that "adaptive" behaviour, but, I was assuming it must be using something like it, some change somewhere else as input increased. So maybe some people can see why this was "unintuitive" or counter to intuition for a beginner. This is why I stated in comments "I might miss something about the circuitry", as I predicted it must be some "adaptive" response, and that was what I missed. But hard to look for what when you do not know what to look for or where to start.

In digital circuits, the emitter is grounded. I stated as much as I could in my follow-up question with same topic that I do understand transistors in digital context, but, based on that understanding, the range of inputs diff amps allow made zero sense. And, this is actually reasonable. I had a shallow understanding, but it worked in digital context. With my shallow "digital" understanding, diff amp inputs were very counter-intuitive.